# MySQLi- How to get number of records in one table that do not match values in another table

Tags: php, mysqli

Sorry for the obscure title... I don't know how best to explain this.

I have two tables, `valid_sizes` and `items`

valid_sizes:

```
ID    SizeID    Description
1     40        Small
2     41        Medium
3     42        Large
```

items:

```
ID    Size
1     41
2     41
3     40
4     99
5     42
6     98
```

I am attempting to perform a query that finds how many items exist whose size does not exist in the `valid_sizes` table. In this instance, a query that would return `2`. (Items 4 and 6 do not exist as a SizeID)

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You want to do a left join, and check for NULL results.

```
   SELECT * FROM items
    LEFT JOIN valid_sizes ON items.SizeID = valid_sizes.Size
    WHERE 
    Size IS NULL;
```